# I am able to fire an event even without using aura:registerEvent tag. In which scenarios do we need to use this tag?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have created a sample notifier and handler for implementing a application event.
The event is firing even when i dont use aura:registerEvent in the notifier.

**Then what is the actual use of this tag? In which scenarios do we absolutely need it? Is it just a best practice to use the tag?**

Below is a code where i didnt use aura:registerEvent tag:

MyEvent :

```
<aura:event type="APPLICATION">
    <aura:attribute name="message" type="String"/>
</aura:event>
```

MyNotifier:

```
<aura:component>
    <h1>Application Event Sample</h1>
    <p><lightning:button
        label="Click here to fire an application event"
        onclick="{!c.fireApplicationEvent}" />
    </p>
</aura:component>
```

MyNotifierController:

```
({
    fireApplicationEvent : function(cmp, event) {
        var appEvent = $A.get("e.c:MyEvent");
        appEvent.setParams({
            "message" : "An application event fired me. "
        });
        appEvent.fire();
    }
})
```

MyHandler :

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="messageFromEvent" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="numEvents" type="Integer" default="0"/>

    <aura:handler event="c:MyEvent" action="{!c.handleApplicationEvent}"/>

    <p>{!v.messageFromEvent}</p>
    <p>Number of events: {!v.numEvents}</p>
</aura:component>
```

MyHandlerController:

```
({
    handleApplicationEvent : function(cmp, event) {
        var message = event.getParam("message");
        cmp.set("v.messageFromEvent", message);
        var numEventsHandled = parseInt(cmp.get("v.numEvents")) + 1;
        cmp.set("v.numEvents", numEventsHandled);
    }
})
```

MyApplication:

```
<aura:application >
    <c:MyNotifier/>
    <c:MyHandler/>
</aura:application>
```

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation.

**For Application Event:**

> A component registers that it may fire an application event by using
>    in its markup. The name attribute is required but
>   not used for application events. The name attribute is only relevant
>   for component events. This example uses name="appEvent" but the value
>   isn’t used anywhere.

Syntax for Application Event:

```
var appEvent = $A.get("e.c:appEvent");
// Optional: set some data for the event (also known as event shape)
// A parameter’s name must match the name attribute
// of one of the event’s <aura:attribute> tags
//appEvent.setParams({ "myParam" : myValue });
appEvent.fire();
```

**For Component Event**

> To get a reference to a component event in JavaScript, use
>   cmp.getEvent("evtName") where evtName matches the name attribute in
>   .
>
> Use fire() to fire the event from an instance of a component. For
>   example, in an action function in a client-side controller:

Syntax For Component Event:

```
<aura:registerEvent name="sampleComponentEvent" type="c:compEvent"/>

var compEvent = cmp.getEvent("sampleComponentEvent");
// Optional: set some data for the event (also known as event shape)
// A parameter’s name must match the name attribute
// of one of the event’s <aura:attribute> tags
// compEvent.setParams({"myParam" : myValue });
compEvent.fire();
```

As I can see 2 Points

1. Component Events are referenced from component using  **cmp.getEvent("sampleComponentEvent");** the component markup shouldUse Register Event to alias it for future use in Javascript
2. Applicantion events are referenced globally using **$A.get("e.c:appEvent");**. As they are present in the whole application thus you can use it without declaring it in markup.

Its not just about custom Application Event, standard salesforce events like refreshView ,e.force:navigateToURL etc can be fired without registering them.

The mention about registerEvent for Application Event is mostly for Code Readability and Make syntax uniform for Application and Component Event.

SRC: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_component_fire.htm?search_text=aura:registerEvent

SRC: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_application_fire.htm

Comment: Is it possible to handle a component event from another component? Is it required to be a parent or it will also work if it is in the same application as well?

Comment: from the Docs > A component event can be handled by the component that fired the event or by a component in the containment hierarchy that receives the event.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is the use the `<aura:registerEvent>` tag, for a number of reasons:

1. As @PranayJaiswal mentioned, code readability
2. If you have complex and multi-layered components, declaring this tag can help with code maintainability in the future.
3. Registering an event will prevent a deployment that doesn't contain the event component - which is desired when moving code from org to org.  It can be frustrating to see an app working in a sandbox/scratch org and then not working in production, all because you forgot to include the appEvent.evt file in the deployment
4. I've seen inconsistent behavior in lightning components when I don't declare this.